# getting the sum of three entries to be the value of another entry automatically in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, sum

```
lbl_ftest = Label(manage_frame2, text="Test 1",bg="gold", fg="black", font=("times new roman",13,"bold"))
    lbl_ftest.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=5, padx=3,sticky="w")

    txt_ftest = Entry(manage_frame2, textvariable=self.ftest_var, font=("times new roman",13,"bold"), bd=3, relief=GROOVE)
    txt_ftest.grid(row=1,column=1, padx=3,pady=5, sticky="w")
    
    lbl_stest = Label(manage_frame2, text="Test 2",bg="gold", fg="black", font=("times new roman",13,"bold"))
    lbl_stest.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=5, padx=3,sticky="w")

    txt_stest = Entry(manage_frame2, textvariable=self.stest_var, font=("times new roman",13,"bold"), bd=3, relief=GROOVE)
    txt_stest.grid(row=2,column=1, padx=3,pady=5, sticky="w")
    
    lbl_Ttest = Label(manage_frame2, text="Test 3",bg="gold", fg="black", font=("times new roman",13,"bold"))
    lbl_Ttest.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=5, padx=3,sticky="w")

    txt_Ttest = Entry(manage_frame2, textvariable=self.Ttest_var, font=("times new roman",13,"bold"), bd=2, relief=GROOVE)
    txt_Ttest.grid(row=3,column=1, padx=2,pady=5, sticky="w")
    
    lbl_CASum = Label(manage_frame2, text="CASum",bg="gold", fg="black", font=("times new roman",13,"bold"))
    lbl_CASum.grid(row=4, column=0, pady=5, padx=3,sticky="w")

    txt_CASum = Entry(manage_frame2, textvariable=self.CASum_var, font=("times new roman",13,"bold"), bd=3, relief=GROOVE)
    txt_CASum.grid(row=4,column=1, padx=3,pady=5, sticky="w")
```

i am trying to sum three Entries (ftest,stest and Ttest) and make the result the value of another entry (CASum)

```
def sum_of_ca(self):
    result = self.CASum_var() #the textvariable of the new entry to hold the value summed
    result.set(self.ftest_var.get() + self.stest_var.get()+self.Ttest_var.get())
```

is there any means to trigger the new entry so it update itself as values are been passed into the varibles to be summed together?

Comment: It is better to provide a [mre].

Comment: You can just execute `self.CASum_var.set(self.ftest_var.get() + self.stest_var.get() + self.Ttest_var.get())` inside `sum_of_ca()`.

Comment: this will still require a button. I want it to be auto sum as the values of the required entries are been entered

Comment: just like an eventlistner

Comment: Then you need to *trace* the three variables using `.trace_add()`.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the sum to be executed automatically when the entries are being entered, you can use `.trace_add()` on the three variables:

```py
self.ftest_var.trace_add('write', self.sum_of_ca)
self.stest_var.trace_add('write', self.sum_of_ca)
self.Ttest_var.trace_add('write', self.sum_of_ca)
```

Then update `sum_of_ca()` as below:

```py
def sum_of_ca(self, *args):
    try:
        self.CASum_var.set(self.ftest_var.get()+self.stest_var.get()+self.Ttest_var.get())
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
```